# ActiveRecord mapping date to TimeWithZone instead of DateTime with .000000 suffix

Tags: ruby, datetime, activerecord, rails-activerecord, activesupport

Like in the title, the program map DateTime to TimeWithZone itself.

```
create_table :db_values do |t|
    t.datetime :created_date
end
```

record from database:
2016-02-01T01:00:00+0000.000000

How can I remove that suffix? '.000000'
I used :

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db]= lambda { |time|  time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z") }
```

Comment: How can I remove '.000000' from date format?

Answer (score 0):

Rails will save all times/timestamps in UTC timezone into your DB. This way it is easier to know exactly to what time it should compare it later when you give it a time in some other timezone. So, don't try to change the DB values to zoned time values. Go with the flow...

When it comes to displaying localized times, just use helper method `I18n.l Time.current`.

Here are a couple of [good articles](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones) about [timezones in Rails](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/).